# Windows/Unix line ending issues?

Tags: vim, newline

I have a couple files that were recently edited on windows and via Cpanel's file editor and now show up double spaced (as in an extra line CR/LF between each line).  Vim is telling me (via `:set ff?`) the file format is `unix` (and I'm working on a Mac).  If I show special characters via `:set list` all the lines just end in `$`.  I tried setting the format via `:e ++ff=mac` which appears to remove all line breaks in the currently edited document and when I write the file and re-open it's back to being double spaced.  I also tried searching and replacing `^M` and various `\r\n` combinations.  I know I'm missing something simple but can someone shed some light on what is going on?  Is this even a line ending issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a line ending issue.

The Vim wiki has this to say on the subject:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format#Terminator_after_last_line

I, however, for expediency, when faced with a line ending problem, use BBEdit on my Mac to change them to Unix (I share, on the LAN, my eight Linux boxes with a Macbook Pro so I use a directory in Dropbox to transfer files across. scp will do the same job).

Unless you have a copy of BBEdit lying about, you can download Barebones's free Text Wrangler & it'll do the same job. Only works on a Mac obviously...

Comment: Phil - First thank you.  I downloaded TextWrangler and opened it  and it says the file is `Unix (LF)` formatted with a encoding of `Unicode (UTF-8)`.  Changing it has zero effect on the formatting no matter which choice I made.  Could it be an encoding issue?  I'm also wondering if perhaps it had windows endings and Cpanel converted it to unix format so now it's legitimately double spaced (not a line terminator issue)?